# Content Provider - Usage

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, concept, android-threading

I have never worked on content providers. so, I have a basic definition kind of knowledge about it.
All I know about them is,

> Content Providers manages access to a **structured set of data**. and, it **encapsulates** the data and provides mechanisms for **defining data security**. It is the standard interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process.

Can anyone give me a practical example that denotes the real-time usage of content providers to understand it accurately?

Comment: here is an example of a content provider by udacity https://github.com/udacity/android-content-provider

Comment: As for real time usage i use it to access audios,videos,images,pdf and other files from my device storage.

Comment: You can search for content provider tutorials on youtube.Best is to watch udacity video content on content provider.